# Java How to pass the value of a parent class variable to an inheriting object

Tags: java

I'm working on a air traffic tower exercise. I have an Aircraft class with two variables id and idCounter. The class is inherited by 3 other classes - 3 types of aircraft.
I use the factory design pattern to create objects from each of those 3 types, the objects are saved in an ArrayList upon creation. Each object is supposed to have a unique id, and I am supposed to use idCounter to determine it.

I have written the following method

```
public long nextId() {
    setIdCounter(getIdCounter()+1);
    return idCounter;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    Id = nextId();
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to update the id of the objects, all ids are stuck on 0.

I've tried calling the set method with

```
arrayName.get(i).setId();
```

but it can't see it and asks me to create a `setId()` method in the interface implemented by the inheriting classes.

I've also tried doing this

```
public long nextId() {
    setId(getIdCounter()+1);
    return id;
}
```

and calling it with

```
arrayName.get(i).nextId();
```

but it won't work since nextId isn't static and if I make it static I have to make id static as well.

How can I call this main or tell my objects to update their id?

Aircraft class code

```
public class Aircraft {

    protected long  Id; 
    protected String name;
    protected Coordinates coordinates;
    private long idCounter;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
    public long getIdCounter() {
        return idCounter;
    }
    public void setIdCounter(long idCounter) {
        this.idCounter = idCounter;
    }
    public Aircraft( String name, Coordinates coordinates) {

        this.name = name;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public long nextId() {
        setIdCounter(getIdCounter()+1);
        return idCounter;
    }
}
```

Factory class

```
public class ConcreteAircraftFactory extends AircraftFactory {

    public Flyable newAircraft (String type, String name, int longitude, int latitude, int height){

        Coordinates coord = Coordinates.makeCoordinate(longitude, latitude, height);

        if (type.equals("Baloon") || type.equals("baloon")) {
            return new Baloon(name, coord);
        }

        else if(type.equals("JetPlane") || type.equals("jetplane") || type.equals("Jetplane")) {
            return new JetPlane(name, coord);
        }

        else if(type.equals("Helicopter") || type.equals("helicopter")) {
            return new Helicopter(name, coord);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Main

```
ArrayList<Flyable> ar = new ArrayList<Flyable>();

for (int i = 1; i <FileReader.fileList.size(); i++) {
     ar.add(factory.newAircraft(FileReader.fileList.get(i)[0], FileReader.fileList.get(i)[1], Integer.parseInt(FileReader.fileList.get(i)[2]), 
            Integer.parseInt(FileReader.fileList.get(i)[3]), Integer.parseInt(FileReader.fileList.get(i)[4])));
}
```

One of the inheriting classes (all have the same implementation)

```
public class JetPlane extends Aircraft  implements Flyable{

private WeatherTower weatherTower;
private String text;

public JetPlane( String name, Coordinates coordinates) {
    super( name, coordinates);

}


public void updateConditions() {
    weatherTower= new WeatherTower();
    String newWeather = weatherTower.getWeather(coordinates);

    switch(newWeather) {

    case WeatherType.FOG:
        coordinates.setLatitude(coordinates.getLatitude()+1);
        text ="JetPlane #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): it's really foggy down there";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
            out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;

    case WeatherType.RAIN:
        coordinates.setLatitude(coordinates.getLatitude()+5);
        text ="JetFighter #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): it's raining hard here";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
            out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;

    case WeatherType.SUN:
        coordinates.setHeight(coordinates.getHeight()+2);
        coordinates.setLatitude(coordinates.getLatitude()+10);
        text ="JetFighter #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): flying in the sun is so much fun";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
            out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;

    case WeatherType.SNOW:
        coordinates.setHeight(coordinates.getHeight()-7);
        text ="JetFighter #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): that thing about winter that guy from that tv show once said";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
            out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    break;
    }

    if(coordinates.getHeight()<0) {
        coordinates.setHeight(0);
    }
    if(coordinates.getHeight()>100) {
        coordinates.setHeight(100);
    }
    if (coordinates.getHeight()==0) {
        weatherTower.unregister(this); //de vazut
        text ="Tower says: JetPlane #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): has been unrergistered";
        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
            out.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void registerTower(WeatherTower weatherTower) {
    weatherTower.register(this);
    text ="Tower says: JetPlane #" + this.getName() + "(" + this.getId() + "): has been rergistered";
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.txt", true))){
        out.println(text);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: Your setId method expects a long as a parameter. So you cannot call it with empty parameters. But you actually don't use the passed long in any way. Why did you define it as setId(long id) when you do nothing with the passed id?

Comment: Can you share the code of Abstract class and the code creating the inheriting aircrafts?

Comment: Please provide all classes. Is it hardly possible to answer a question about inheritation without those.

Comment: If Ids are supposed to be unique, with counter making sure of that and all I don't see why would you try to call `setId` at any point after aircraft creation.

Comment: @arkantos, reporter Updated with code, sorry. I have made a mistake. Aircraft isn't abstract but I am still not allowed to create any instances of it.

Comment: @Deltharis Isn't set used to attribute a new value to the variable. The objects do see id so I though it was a problem of setting the correct value. I'm new to java

Comment: @Oh God Spiders. That was left over from something else I've tried. Thanks for pointing it out, completely missed it.

Comment: Ok, I see the most problematic point - how is idCounter supposed to work? If you want to use it to get unique id for new aircrafts... Than it can't be a part of aircraft instance, that way every single aircraft just has a different one

Comment: @Deltharis Making it static and adding it to the constructor worked. Thank you. If you'll make it an answer I'll +1 you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be more helpful if I can see the code, but I think it would work if you make this 'idCounter' a static variable.

```
static long idCounter;
```

Comment: Updated with code. Sorry about that. I'm not allowed to redefine access modifiers for anything.

Comment: Making it static and adding it to the constructor worked. Thank you.